# Current week in webpage

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code , everything works fine except $w which should be present week number .

```
  $w="WEEKOFYEAR()";
```

I have declared everything and my code works when i hard code the week number

```
$w=13;

insert($actual,$target['value'],$country,$ini,$goal ,$comment,$an,$w,$con);
```

I get the following error : Instead of it showing week number 13; it is starting from 0

Comment: I believe the error is very self explanatory:  The function `WEEKOFYEAR` is undefined (i.e. it doesn't exist).

Comment: Apart from it not existing, why do you have WEEKOFYEAR() in quotes?

Comment: A simple google yields plenty of results. Please try to search before you ask.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `WEEKOFYEAR()` is not a default PHP function. Use `date()` to get the present week number.

```
$w = date('W');
```

**Note that the "W" is a capital W, it makes a difference.**

Also, check out the PHP documentation for `date()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current week, you may try this

```
$weekNumber = date("W");
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php